# Comparing results with Pyephem

Tags: orbital-mechanics, ephemeris

I'm trying to calculate the position of each satellite of the GPS constalation, using [TLE](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/gps-ops.txt) files and library [pyephem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem), I want to know the position Elevation-Azimuth. But when I compare with the results with the page [calsky](https://www.calsky.com/cs.cgi) with the results of my code are diferents, **why**?

The initial information are:
Bogotá, Colombia
**Longitude** = -74.0817
**Latitude**  = 4.60971
**Alt**: 2578.0
**Date:** 2017-04-18 **Hour:** 10:08:51.61

> Results in CALSKY >45º

**PRN 27/GPS BIIF-(39166 2013-023-A)**  az: 152.7° SSE  h:  61.1°
**PRN 16/GPS BIIR-(27663 2003-005-A)**  az: 341.8° NNW  h:  52.5°
**PRN 14/GPS BIIR-(26605 2000-071-A)**  az: 109.5° ESE  h:  49.5°

> Results in my code > 45º

**GPS BIIR-7  (PRN 18)**  - azim: 27.68  elev: 58.34
**GPS BIIR-9  (PRN 21)**  - azim: 200.54  elev: 55.05
**GPS BIIF-1  (PRN 25)**  - azim: 111.35  elev: 46.92

```
def GetPositionELAZ(Time,Longitude,Latitude,constelation,AllTheLines):
'''
- time: Time for look the satellite
- longitude: observer longitude
- latitude: observer latitude
- constelation: 
            1 - just GPS 
            2 - GPS - GLONASS
            3 - GPS - GLONASS - GALILEO
            
RETURN: (Tuble of lists...)
Satellite Name, Satellite Elevation, Satellite Azimuth, Type Satellite (1:GPS, 2: GLO, 3:GAL)
'''

contain_GPS = 'GPS'
contain_GLONASS = 'COSMOS'
contain_GALILEO = 'GSAT'

sat_alt, sat_az, sat_name, sat_type = [], [], [], []
original_name = []

longlat = str(Longitude) + "," + str(Latitude)
g = geocoder.elevation(longlat) #lon,lat
#print g.meters
import ephem
observer = ephem.Observer()
observer.long = Longitude
observer.lat = Latitude
observer.date = Time
observer.elevation = 2600. #float(str(g.meters))

GPS_list = 'https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/gps-ops.txt'
GLONASS_list = 'https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/glo-ops.txt'
GALILEO_list = 'https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/galileo.txt'

#'http://www.amsat.org/amsat/ftp/keps/current/nasabare.txt').readlines()
GPS2_list = 'http://www.tle.info/data/gps-ops.txt'
GLONASS2_list = 'http://www.tle.info/data/glo-ops.txt'

if constelation == 1:
    list_TLEs = [GPS_list]
if constelation == 2:
    list_TLEs = [GPS_list,GLONASS_list]
if constelation == 3:
    list_TLEs = [GPS_list,GLONASS_list,GALILEO_list]

for satlist in list_TLEs:
    tles = AllTheLines #urllib2.urlopen(satlist).readlines() 
    tles = [item.strip() for item in tles]
    tles = [(tles[i],tles[i+1],tles[i+2]) for i in xrange(0,len(tles)-2,3)]
    
    for tle in tles:

        try:
            sat = ephem.readtle(tle[0], tle[1], tle[2])
            rt, ra, tt, ta, st, sa = observer.next_pass(sat)

            if rt is not None and st is not None:
                sat.compute(observer)

                if Time >= ephem.localtime(st) and Time <= ephem.localtime(rt):
                    Title = tle[0]
                    sat_alt.append(np.rad2deg(sat.alt))
                    sat_az.append(np.rad2deg(sat.az))
                    original_name.append(tle[0])

                    text2 = Title.rsplit(')', 1)[0]
                    NamePRN = text2.rsplit('(', 1)[1]
                    sat_name.append(NamePRN)

                    if contain_GPS in Title:
                        sat_type.append(1)
                    elif contain_GLONASS in Title:
                        sat_type.append(2)
                    elif contain_GALILEO in Title:
                        sat_type.append(3)

        except ValueError as e:
            print e
return sat_name, sat_alt, sat_az, sat_type, original_name
```

> Calling the function

```
GPS_list = 'https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/gps-ops.txt'
Downloaded = urllib2.urlopen(GPS_list).readlines()
TimeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
print Time2SecondsOfDay(TimeNow), 'time: ',TimeNow

names,elevs,azs,types,originalName = 
GetPositionELAZ(TimeNow,Longitude,Latitude,1,Downloaded)
```

Comment: I hope see the same vehicles in the same time, but I only see others vehicles, but I don't know why is not the same. for compare a few vehicles only I show the satellites over 45º.

Comment: This probably isn't helpful, but you have your latitude and longitude reversed. Let me know if that does/doesn't help.

Comment: thank you @barrycarter I had the wrong latitude/longitude, I updated the results (and the question), although I find some differences in the results yet.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the TLE information will give you the orbit. From that, you get compute the position and velocity of the spacecraft in the ECI frame. However, you need to convert that to the ECEF frame in order to compute the altitude and elevation information, and I don't see that happening in your code. That said, if there is a library that works well, why do you need to recode such a feature, and not just use the library that works?

Comment: Also, what's the code from `sat.compute()`? Could the reference frame conversion happen there?

Comment: thanks @ChrisR , about the ECEF and ECI frame, when you are looking for elevation and azimuth, doesnt matter the frame, but you need the elevation of the location (I use the library geocoder for this) because the elevation and azimuth is respect to the horizon

Comment: @mikesneider No, frames (almost) always matter. You cannot subtract the vector of the satellite expressed in the ECI frame with the position of the station which is commonly expressed in ECEF.

Comment: @ChrisR the literal answer is: "To be precise, the reference frame of the Earth-centered inertial (ECI) coordinates produced by the SGP4/SDP4 orbital model is true equator, mean equinox (TEME) of epoch". [source](https://celestrak.com/columns/v04n05/#FAQ08)

Answer (score 3):

I figured out,It was something wrong in the code:
The function `observer.next_pass(sat)`, return a vector of 5 values

> 0  Rise time
>   1  Rise azimuth
>   2  Maximum altitude time
>   3  Maximum altitude
>   4  Set time
>   5  Set azimuth

So the instruction `if Time >= ephem.localtime(st) and Time <= ephem.localtime(rt):` I was using a innecesary comparation because you already compute the time with the instruction `observer.date = Time` 
also
I was comparing with the localtime, the best option is have all in UTC time.
and a advice with satellites don't use `datetime.now()`, use `datetime.utcnow()`, and later you can add the GTM of your region.